# How to know if Dev renounced ownership of smart contract?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ether, etherscan

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if someone can show the difference between a renounced and unrenounced coding that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> Also if someone can show the difference between a renounced and unrenounced

**Edit:**

I answered this too hastily... :-)

Distinctions do exist between the two, but you'd have to dig through the contract code and the relevant transaction logs to be able to prove what someone is telling you.

For example, a contract could contain an `transferOwnership()` function, and that function could set the contract `owner` as a known burn address, e.g. `0x00...000`.

A case in point would be the [Sablier](https://sablier.com/) contract, which renounced ownership in [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3c8fbe1356ffe572e0bda6d1e69e78b12e0fe7549715b3124ad5db233eb2a098) transaction by calling `OwnershipTransferred()`. (See the transaction logs, [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3c8fbe1356ffe572e0bda6d1e69e78b12e0fe7549715b3124ad5db233eb2a098#eventlog).)

Comment: Just as a follow-up, every token out there is basically lying about the token being renounced then? Thank you!

Comment: Could you give some examples of tokens bring renounced?

Comment: I can't give an example. I just see a bunch of tokens making this claim. I don't understand their justification. I thought someone else in here could provide insight into this marketing ploy for people to put money into tokens.

Comment: Actually - you've got a point. I'd seen various threads where "we burned the admin keys" turned out not to be true - updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to your question.

A smart contract can have any number of backdoors. These include "owner only" function. And those are typically limited to the owner which may "renounce" as you mentioned.

**But** if the owner has any other form of undue influence over the smart contract, such as outsided token positions, a controlling voting block of governance tokens, knowledge of exploits, special numbers, etc. then "renouncing ownership" only removes one of the mechanisms that person can use to assert control over the contract.

---

One example of a renouncing is 0xcert's protocol token. Here is the blog post explaining that: https://0xcert.org/news/decentralizing-zxc-ownership/ including all technical details and practical aspects.